# How to change the background color of RawTurtle

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, background-color, turtle-graphics

I wrote a python script, which should open a Tkinter window with a canvas and let turtle draw in this canvas. Now I want to change the background color of the canvas, but it stays always white (default settings of `RawTurtle`?). Is there any possibility to draw on a background with another color?

```
from Tkinter import *
import turtle
root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(1)

ccanvas = Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 480)

ccanvas.pack()

turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(ccanvas)
turtle = turtle.bgcolor("black")

mainloop()
```

If I try `turtle = turtle.bgcolor("black")` the error looks like this: `'RawTurtle' object has no attribute 'bgcolor'`.

Comment: `ccanvas.config(bg='red')`

Comment: `ccanvas.config(bg='red')` is not working. `RawTurtle` is overwriting the background of the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a `turtle.TurtleScreen` (provides a `bgcolor` method) to `turtle.RawTurtle` instead of directly using `Canvas` :

```
ccanvas = Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 480)

turtle_screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(ccanvas)
turtle_screen.bgcolor("black")

ccanvas.pack()

turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(turtle_screen)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ccanvas.configure(background='black')
```

Comment: It would help if you reread the question at least once before answering as you completely missed the point on this.  You're talking *foreground* color while the OP is talking *background* color.